# How to build Sp_send_dbmail attachment string from query results

Tags: sql, sql-server, do-while, sp-send-dbmail

I need to attach a file for each result in a query, could be a single result could be 10. Using Microsoft SQL server 2012.

example: `select ItemNumber from table where column_x=22:`

Results:

> 125487,
>
> 25645124

```
Declare @path nvarchar(255);
Set @path = 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\'

Declare @attachment nvarchar(255);
  Set @attachment = @path + result1 + '.txt' + ',' + @path + result2 + '.txt'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[GetItems]
@TransNumber INT,
 @attachment nvarchar(MAX)  OUTPUT
AS 

 Begin

 DECLARE @path nvarchar(255);
 SET @path = 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\WineCards\';
 set @attachment = ''


 SELECT @attachment += CONCAT(';', @path, 'wn', ItemLookupcode, '.pdf')
 FROM TransactionEntry
 Left Join Item on TransactionEntry.ItemID = Item.ID
 WHERE TransactionEntry.TransactionNumber=@TransNumber and         dbo.fn_FileExists(CONCAT(@path, 'wn', ItemLookupcode, '.pdf') )=1
 Group by Itemlookupcode
```

;

select @attachment = STUFF(@attachment, 1, 1, ''); -- remove initial ";"

End